# Save only part of the database?

Tags: redis

is it possible to maintain persistence on only part of the data?

For example, lets say I have keys in the format "xyz" and "xyz:a", would there be a way of only keeping the "xyz"?

edit: had already read the persistence doc from them, was really just wondering if there was a workaround for it, thanks anyway

Comment: for anyone interested, what i end up doing is separate the keys in 2 instances, this will allow you to create different configuration files and define the respective persistence you want to use. This is also allow to make use of another core of your machine

Comment: I was going to suggest a work around of a similar nature.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Also, look at [redis persistent model](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) to understand how it's work.